Pystray doesn't work when I compile my code with PyInstaller
My Python code works fine normally, but after compiling it with PyInstaller, pystray doesn't work. I'm getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pystray/_xorg.py", line 162, in _update_icon
  File "pystray/_xorg.py", line 395, in _assert_docked
AssertionError
Failed to dock icon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pystray/_xorg.py", line 143, in _show
  File "pystray/_xorg.py", line 395, in _assert_docked
AssertionError

Here is the relevant part of my code:
import pystray
from pystray import MenuItem as item

def create_tray():
    icon_image = Image.open("icon.png")
    tray_menu = (item('Show', lambda: show_app()), item('Quit', lambda: quit_program()))
    tray_icon = pystray.Icon("EasyLinux", icon_image, menu=pystray.Menu(*tray_menu))
    threading.Thread(target=tray_icon.run, daemon=True).start()

create_tray()

Does anyone know how to fix this?
I was expecting the program's icon to appear in the system tray with pystray.
